# Tips for interacting with debian based repositories

Tags: python, deb

I am planning on writing a small program that interacts with a debian based repository - namely doing a partial mirror**. I am planning to write it in python.

What are some tips for working with the repository including already constructed 'wheels' (to save the invention of yet another one)?

Some issues I have identified

- As it is going to be a partial mirror, I will need to regenerate the package lists (Release,Contents*, Packages.{bz2,gz}). (Maybe debian-installer can do it for me??)
- How to get changes to package list (I already know that packages do not change, but that the lists only link to the latest file)?

** Already looked into apt-mirror and debmirror. Debmirror is the closest to what I want, however lacking in some features. If apt can deal with multiple releases and architectures then I will consider apt.

Answer (score 0):

debian-installer doesn't generate repository metadata. For that, you want a tool like `reprepro` or `mini-dinstall`. They'll also handle the second point you raised.